# How to make tooltip display beside every image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tooltip

I have several images that I applied jQuery tooltip effect on..it works, but the problem is that irrespective of the image i click the tooltip only displays at the top of the page.
Is there a way I can make the tooltip appear beside each image that is clicked.

The jQuery I have so far looks like this :

```
$('.image').hover(function () {
    $('.tooltip').fadeIn(1000);
}, function () {
    $('.tooltip').fadeOut(1000);
});

$('.tooltip').css({
   top: e.pageY,
   left: e.pageX
})
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #D1C585;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid rgba(128, 0, 32, 0.3);
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: actor;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="image">
```

Comment: You need to set the position of the tooltip somewhere, is that handled in the plug-in itself, because it looks like it's defaulting to `left: 0; top: 0;`.

Comment: Where is the element with the class "tooltip"?

Comment: I don't want to discourage you from creating your own, but I do want to make sure you are aware of the tooltip jQuery plugin in twitter bootstrap http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Comment: And now you have added more code, what happened to the formatting, as demonstrated by my  edit just recently?

Comment: doesn't look like you are using jqueryui's tooltip? look.. http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/

Answer (score 0):

It needs to have `position: absolute` and its parent has to be `position: relative`. Inside the hover function do:

```
$('.tooltip').css({
  top: e.pageY,
  left: e.pageX
})
```

Comment: I added the script you provided, but still displaying at the top left corner of the page. Thanks

Comment: you also need to change function() to function(e)

Comment: Can you please be explicit, my knowledge of jQUery is quite basic. Thank you

Comment: Thanks David.. One more thing. How can I make the tooltip not overflow beyond the frame of the browser. [link](http://types4u.org/ema/pastors-desk.php) ... When you mouseover the the image on the right margin, notice what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on where the location of the tooltip node is located. However, you can get the fixed position of the image by grabbing and adding all the offsetLeft/offsetTop of all the element and it's parents. For example.

```
$('.image').hover(function() {
    var e = this,top=0,left=0;
    while(e){
        top+=e.offsetTop;
        left+=e.offsetLeft;
        e=$(e).parent();
    }
    $(this).css({position:'fixed',top:top+"px",left:left:left+"px"});
    $('.tooltip').fadeIn(1000);
}, function() {
    $('.tooltip').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

I did not test this code. However, I hope this points you in the right direction. You can then use the size of the image(offsetHeight and offsetWidth) to position the tooltip around the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using jquery ui, see [jquery ui tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) for documentation

HTML

```
<img src="http://img262.imageshack.us/img262/68/sahara4rs.jpg" title="tyre">
```

Javascript

```
$(document).tooltip({
    track: true,
    show: {
        effect: "fade",
        delay: 1000
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        delay: 250
    }
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/N2a7x/)